Undo/Redo not working for a Tkinter text widget
I have code for a tkinter text widget using tk and ttkbootstrap:
(part of code)
usertext = tb.Text(frame,width=95,
     height=24,borderwidth=textandlineborder,wrap="none",autostyle=False,undo=True)
usertext.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="NSEW",pady=0,padx=0)
usertext.configure(autoseparators=True)
usertext.configure(maxundo=-1)

However, when I try using Ctrl + Z or Ctrl Y, the caret (text cursor) moves around, but the text stays the same. It doesn't undo/redo the text at all, but the function is called. What could be the root of this issue?
(My code is very long so I can't upload it all, if there's any other data I should provide just ask)
I tried changing around some values and stuff but it still didn't work.

Can you [edit] this into a [mre]? Otherwise we'll have to make assumptions about how your code is put together

I cannot reproduce the issue with the provided code, undo/redo works fine. However, redo is not bound to Ctrl+Y by default,  but to Ctrl+Shift+Z

Its nearly 2300 lines, and I personally have no clue where the issue is. Plus, the code relys on multiple dependencies and other files. Should I send a link to a zip or something?

@MuhammadHamzaNaveed copy your project into a new folder and remove stuff until you get a [mre] (usually <50 lines of code). Most of the time, by doing that, you will find out what the problem is. The code you provided is fine and should work as expected.

Alright, I will try this and send an update once I'm done.

This question is similar to: Undo and redo features in a Tkinter Text widget?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Sure! I have enabled both the undo, autoseperators=True. and maxundo=-1. still not working. I'm currently sifting through my code for the minimal reproducible example.
